# How best to incorporate groupby in a loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, group-by

I'm a novice R user and am using a loop to update a rating for a participant in an event within my data frame. I got the loop working for a unique participant when I filtered it from my larger data frame. If I add more participants and include `groupby(Participant)` to the loop, or other suggested methods I've looked up, the rating updates per row rather than by individual participant.

My data frame consists of around 120,000 rows, around 15,000 participants and I've read loops can be slow. I've also looked at the apply family but can't see how that would work with my data but more than happy to be corrected and save time!

The rating is based somewhat on the ELO methodology but isn't a pairwise comparison and I've tweaked the formula to suit my requirements. On paper it works so would love some help to replicate it in R.

Below we have the equivalent of the data frame I'm working with. Using the `New_rating`, I'd use the loop to produce a rating for each subsequent Event per Participant. The loop code below is what I used when there was only 1 unique participant and it worked perfectly. If that can be edited to work, happy days but any solution would be greatly appreciated!

```
df <- data.frame(Participant = c("A", "B", "A", "C", "B", "A", "C"))
df$Event <- c(1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2)
df$Initial_rating <- 1500
df$Result <- c(-4.507,25.488,18.113,-11.333,-5.083,0.507,8.667)
df$New_rating <- c(1495.493,1525.488,0,1488.667,0,0,0)
n <- nrow(df)
for (i in 2:n) {
df$New_rating[i] <- (df$New_rating[i-1] + df$Result[i])
}
```

Comment: Could you add a new column `desired_new_rating` to your sample data so the goal is clear?

Comment: To your premise that *"loops can be slow"*, since R-3.6 or so, `for` loops are much faster, so the performance difference between `for` and `*apply` functions is much lower, where (to me) readability and maintainability is much better. Where the most difference is normally felt is shifting to "vectorized" code from less-efficient code. Having said that, most "experienced" answerers on SO will likely recommend `*apply` thoughts due to experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we want to build on the OP's `for` loop, loop over the `unique` values of 'Participant' column, subset the data based on the looped value ('tmp'), then, do the inner `for` with the 'tmp' data, and update the original dataset after exiting the inner loop

```
df$New_rating2 <- df$New_rating
un1 <- unique(df$Participant)
for(un in un1) {
     i1 <- df$Participant == un     
     tmp <- df[i1,]    
     n <- nrow(tmp)
     for (i in 2:n) {
       tmp$New_rating2[i] <- (tmp$New_rating2[i-1] + tmp$Result[i])
     }
     df[i1, ] <- tmp
}
```

NOTE: There are better ways to do this in a group by operation or `split`, but since the calculation showed is dummy, we are sticking with the OP's `for` loop

---

May also use `accumulate` after grouping by 'Participant'

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df %>%
   group_by(Participant) %>% 
   mutate(New_rating3 = accumulate2(New_rating, Result[-1], 
        ~ ..1 + ..3) %>% flatten_dbl) %>% 
   ungroup
# A tibble: 7 × 7
  Participant Event Initial_rating  Result New_rating New_rating2 New_rating3
  <chr>       <dbl>          <dbl>   <dbl>      <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>
1 A               1           1500  -4.51       1495.       1495.       1495.
2 B               1           1500  25.5        1525.       1525.       1525.
3 A               2           1500  18.1           0        1514.       1514.
4 C               1           1500 -11.3        1489.       1489.       1489.
5 B               2           1500  -5.08          0        1520.       1520.
6 A               3           1500   0.507         0        1514.       1514.
7 C               2           1500   8.67          0        1497.       1497.
```

Comment: Amazing, works a treat, I can't thank you enough!